# Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm looking for a code in python using regex that can perform something like this

Input: `Regex should return "String 1" or "String 2" or "String3"`

Output: `String 1,String2,String3`

I tried `r'"*"'`

Comment: There could be quotes inside quotes, what would you do with that?

Comment: No, there wont be any quotes. Just simple string with a-z , 0-9 whitespaces, underscore, mostly alphanumeric without any single or double quotes inside them3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations)

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Here's all you need to do:

```
def doit(text):      
  import re
  matches = re.findall(r'"(.+?)"',text)
  # matches is now ['String 1', 'String 2', 'String3']
  return ",".join(matches)

doit('Regex should return "String 1" or "String 2" or "String3" ')
```

result:

```
'String 1,String 2,String3'
```

As pointed out by [Li-aung Yip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1191425/li-aung-yip):

> To elaborate, `.+?` is the "non-greedy" version of `.+`. It makes the regular expression match the smallest number of characters it can instead of the most characters it can. The greedy version, `.+`, will give `String 1" or "String 2" or "String 3`; the non-greedy version `.+?` gives `String 1`, `String 2`, `String 3`.

In addition, if you want to accept empty strings, change `.+` to `.*`. Star `*` means zero or more while plus `+` means at least one.

Comment: To elaborate, `.+?` is the "non-greedy" version of `.+`. It makes the regular expression match the smallest number of characters it can instead of the most characters it can. The greedy version, `.+`, will give `string 1" or "String 2" or "String 3`; the non-greedy version `.+?` gives `String 1`, `String 2`, `String 3`.

Comment: Is it necessary to to escape the double quotes? Since you are using a raw string anyway. Wouldn't `r'"(.+?)"'` suffice? That seems to work on my system.

Comment: @Sam It's not necessary. I went ahead and removed them :)

Answer (score 7):

The highly up-voted answer doesn't account for the possibility that the double-quoted string might contain one or more double-quote characters (properly escaped, of course). To handle this situation, the regex needs to accumulate characters one-by-one with a *positive lookahead assertion* stating that the current character is not a double-quote character that is not preceded by a backslash (which requires a *negative lookbehind assertion*):

```
"(?:(?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)"
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ls5VTU/1/)

```
import re
import ast


def doit(text):
    matches=re.findall(r'"(?:(?:(?!(?<!\\)").)*)"',text)
    for match in matches:
        print(match, '=>', ast.literal_eval(match))


doit('Regex should return "String 1" or "String 2" or "String3" and "\\"double quoted string\\"" ')
```

Prints:

```
"String 1" => String 1
"String 2" => String 2
"String3" => String3
"\"double quoted string\"" => "double quoted string"
```

Comment: This is so clutch and a lifesaver, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Just try to fetch double quoted strings from the multiline string:

```
import re

s = """ 
"my name is daniel"  "mobile 8531111453733"[[[[[[--"i like pandas"
"location chennai"! -asfas"aadhaar du2mmy8969769##69869" 
@4343453 "pincode 642002""@mango,@apple,@berry" 
"""
print(re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', s))
```

Comment: This is the exact same solution as [the accepted answer](/a/9519934/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/69891301/1531728

My solution is:

```
import re
my_strings = ['SetVariables "a" "b" "c" ', 'd2efw   f "first" +&%#$%"second",vwrfhir, d2e   u"third" dwedew', '"uno"?>P>MNUIHUH~!@#$%^&*()_+=0trewq"due"        "tre"fef    fre f', '       "uno""dos"      "tres"', '"unu""doua""trei"', '      "um"                    "dois"           "tres"                  ']
my_substrings = []
for current_test_string in my_strings:
    for values in re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', current_test_string):
        my_substrings.append(values)
        #print("values are:",values,"=")
    print(" my_substrings are:",my_substrings,"=")
    my_substrings = []
```

Alternate regular expressions to use are:

- re.findall('"(.+?)"', current_test_string) [Avinash2021] [user17405772021]
- re.findall('"(.*?)"', current_test_string) [Shelvington2020]
- re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', current_test_string) [Lundberg2012] [Avinash2021]
- re.findall(r'"(.+?)"', current_test_string) [Lundberg2012] [Avinash2021]
- re.findall(r'"["]', current_test_string) [Muthupandi2019]
- re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', current_test_string) [Pieters2014]
- re.findall(r'"(?:(?:(?!(?<!\)").)*)"', current_test_string) # Causes double quotes to remain in the strings, but can be removed via other means. [Booboo2020]
- re.findall(r'"(.*?)(?<!\)"', current_test_string) [Hassan2014]
- re.findall('"[^"]*"', current_test_string) # Causes double quotes to remain in the strings, but can be removed via other means. [Martelli2013]
- re.findall('"([^"]*)"', current_test_string) [jspcal2014]
- re.findall("'(.*?)'", current_test_string) [akhilmd2016]

The `current_test_string.split("\"")` approach works if the strings have patterns in which substrings are embedded within quotation marks. *This is because it uses the double quotation mark in this example as a delimiter to tokenize the string, and accepts substrings that are not embedded within double quotation marks as valid substring extractions from the string.*

References:

- [Avinash2021] Arvind Kumar Avinash, Answer to ``Extract text between quotation using regex python'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, October 12, 2021. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543129/1531728 and [Extract text between quotation using regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542978/extract-text-between-quotation-using-regex-python/69543129#69543129;) November 8, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [user17405772021] user1740577, Answer to ``Extract text between quotation using regex python'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, October 12, 2021. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543030/1531728 and [Extract text between quotation using regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542978/extract-text-between-quotation-using-regex-python/69543030#69543030;) November 8, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Shelvington2020] Iain Shelvington, Answer to ``Extracting only words out of a mixed string in Python [duplicate]'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, January 5, 2020. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59598630/1531728 and [Extracting only words out of a mixed string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598565/extracting-only-words-out-of-a-mixed-string-in-python/59598630#59598630;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Lundberg2012] Johan Lundberg, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 1, 2012. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519934/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/9519934#9519934;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Muthupandi2019] Daniel Muthupandi and trotta, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, August 3, 2019. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337020/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/63707053#63707053;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Booboo2020] Booboo, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63707053/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/63707053#63707053;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Pieters2014] Martijn Pieters, Answer to ``Extract a string between double quotes'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735466/1531728 and [Extract a string between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes/22735466#22735466;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Hassan2014] Sabuj Hassan, Answer to ``Extract a string between double quotes'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735480/1531728 and [Extract a string between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes/22735480#22735480;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Martelli2013] Alex Martelli and Sumit Singh, Answer to "Extract string from between quotations", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, March 14, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076357/1531728 and [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations/2076357#2076357;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [jspcal2014] jspcal, Answer to "Extract string from between quotations", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, March 14, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076356/1531728 and [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations/2076356#2076356;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [akhilmd2016] akhilmd, Answer to "Stripping string in python between quotes", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, July 2, 2016. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38161072/1531728 and ; November 5, 2021 was the last accessed date.

Answer (score 0):

For me the only regex that ever worked right for all the cases of quoted strings with possibly escaped quotes inside of them was:

```
regex=r"""(['"])(?:\\\\|\\\1|[^\1])*?\1"""
```

This will not fail even if the quoted string ends with an escaped backslash.

Answer (score -2):

```py
import re
r=r"'(\\'|[^'])*(?!<\\)'|\"(\\\"|[^\"])*(?!<\\)\""

texts=[r'"aerrrt"',
r'"a\"e'+"'"+'rrt"',
r'"a""""arrtt"""""',
r'"aerrrt',
r'"a\"errt'+"'",
r"'aerrrt'",
r"'a\'e"+'"'+"rrt'",
r"'a''''arrtt'''''",
r"'aerrrt",
r"'a\'errt"+'"',
      "''",'""',""]

for text in texts:
     print (text,"-->",re.fullmatch(r,text))
```

results:

```py
"aerrrt" --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match='"aerrrt"'>
"a\"e'rrt" --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='"a\\"e\'rrt"'>
"a""""arrtt""""" --> None
"aerrrt --> None
"a\"errt' --> None
'aerrrt' --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 8), match="'aerrrt'">
'a\'e"rrt' --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='\'a\\\'e"rrt\''>
'a''''arrtt''''' --> None
'aerrrt --> None
'a\'errt" --> None
'' --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match="''">
"" --> <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 2), match='""'>
 --> None
```

Comment: Can you explain how your answer is working in some details. I am unable to find it according to question asked.