# issues with sentence detection using nltk

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk

I have issues with nltk recognizing this as one sentence, because of the exclamation mark in the quotation marks.

```
s = "Donc ce n'est pas non plus de vous dire « Allez absolument ici ! », non."
```

I tried:

```
from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
sent_tokenize(s, language='french')
```

but I get:

> ["Donc ce n'est pas non plus de vous dire « Allez absolument ici !",
>   '», non.']

I am wondering if there is a better sentence detection method out there ?

Comment: You probably want to take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32003294/sentence-tokenization-for-texts-that-contains-quotes) to start with.

Comment: I'm wondering if you replace the `« »` characters with standard quotes if it will tokenize properly on its own?

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb I actually tried that. No change, unfortunately. :/