# Python Regex extract string from line

Tags: python, regex

I am programming in Python 3.4.
I am reading lines in different files and when I get to the line containing a specific string I want extract only the path string from that line.
Example:

line in file is:

```
TEST_CASE_CHECK = require("TestCases/AOL/TU_Extract_Log_Details")
```

I search for: `require("TestCases`

I want extract only: `TestCases/AOL/TU_Extract_Log_Details`

I know this can be done with regex but I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: please post your attempt.

Comment: Have a look at [*Extract a string between double quotes*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes), might work for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the rest of your lines look like but this should work

```
import re

s = 'TEST_CASE_CHECK = require("TestCases/AOL/TU_Extract_Log_Details")'

mat = re.search(r'(TestCases.*)"',s)
if mat:
    print(mat.group(1))

TestCases/AOL/TU_Extract_Log_Details
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It worked.

Comment: @mariusalex Don't forget to click the green check if this is your desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you are looking for?

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'require\("(TestCases[^"]*)')
test_str = u"TEST_CASE_CHECK = require(\"TestCases/AOL/TU_Extract_Log_Details\")"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```

https://regex101.com/r/zJ0sM3/1

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

line = 'TEST_CASE_CHECK = require("TestCases/AOL/TU_Extract_Log_Details")'

result = re.match(r'.*require.+"([^"]*)".*', line)

print result.groups()[0] # prints "TestCases/AOL/TU_Extract_Log_Details"
```