# How do I scan a sentence in Python

Tags: python, string, nltk

Suppose I have a text file :

> As a manager, he told FIFA TV he communicates his messages in a measured way.
>   “I’m not one of the lads,” Southgate explained.

Is there a way to get the sentence inside the quote (") and save that sentence as variable? I know I have to use the scanner method, but I'm new to python language and I don't know how. Can someone give me an example on how to store this?

Comment: Kindly Have a look at ["How to Extract a string between double quotes"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes)

Comment: The sentence inside `"` have special characters so using it as variable name is not possible. You will need to do add `_` like characters to fill the gap and your task can be done. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop too.

Comment: I would prefer not to use modules such as re as discussed in that topic, just my opinion, but I think they complicate stuff.

Comment: My doubt is, you want to use the string within `"` as a variable name (creating variables dynamically) or you just want to assign this to other variable?

Comment: I just want to get the string inside the " and transform it with another method @RishikeshAgrawani

Comment: There can be multiple substrings inside a string enclosed within `"` or only 1?

Comment: only 1 sentence inside "

Comment: Okay thanks for update. The text `“I’m not one of the lads,”` is not really inside `"` as it has `”`. Please make sure if it is `"` or `”`? I checked it in my editor. If it is `”` then we need to add support for **utf-8**  texts, if it is `"` then it is fine.

Comment: if it is using " how? and if it using ” how? why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be sure that there are always two double-quotes in the strings you're trying to parse, you can simply use `str.split('"')[0]` to extract what's between them.

```
>>> s = '''As a manager, he told FIFA TV he communicates his messages in a measured way. "I’m not one of the lads," Southgate explained.'''
>>> s.split('"')[1]
'I’m not one of the lads,'
```

**Edit**: I now see that your input string actually uses the slanted double-quotes, `“` and `”`, not the standard double-quote, `"`, in which case I suggest that you use the following instead:

```
s = '''As a manager, he told FIFA TV he communicates his messages in a measured way. “I’m not one of the lads,” Southgate explained.'''
print(s[s.find('“') + 1:s.find('”')])
```

This outputs:

```
I’m not one of the lads,
```

Comment: this is just split the sentence into word. what i mean is, to get the sentence inside the "

Comment: Please look closer. It's properly getting the sentence between the quotes: `I’m not one of the lads,`. I just edited my answer to make it easier to read.

Comment: doesnt work even when i paste ur code. the eror says IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: I now see that it is because your input string actually uses the slanted double-quotes, `“` and `”`, not the standard double-quote, `"`.

Comment: they are different?

Comment: Yes they are completely different characters. I've updated my answer with a new solution to account for the special double-quotes that you are using. Please check it out.

Comment: that works. thanks mate. now what is this +1:s.find('”')

Comment: You're welcome. `s.find('“')` returns the index of the first `“` in the string, and by adding one to it, we get the starting index of the sentence you're looking for, up to the ending index, which is found with `s.find('”')`.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to do something like this:

```
file = open("filename.txt","r") # Opens the file
sentence = file.readline().split() # ['A','s',' ','a',' ','m'...]
startQuote = sentence.index('"') # Finds first occurence
endQuote = sentence[startQuote::].index("'") # Finds first occurrence after first quote
stringSentence = ''.join(sentence[startQuote:endQuote:]) # Creates string with splicing
```

If you want the code to accommodate for 'smart quotes', you can simplify it to to:

```
file = open("filename.txt","r") # Opens the file
sentence = file.readline().split() # ['A','s',' ','a',' ','m'...]
startQuote = sentence.index(“) # Finds first occurence
endQuote = sentence.index(”) # Finds first occurrence of end quote
stringSentence = ''.join(sentence[startQuote:endQuote:]) # Creates string with splicing
```

You may have to fix up some 'fence-post-errors' in this code as I have not tested it.

I hope this gives you an idea of what you need to do.

Comment: this ones give me error. the error                                                                              
            said startQuote = sentence.index("\"") # Finds first occurence
ValueError: '"' is not in list

Comment: That may be because, the quotes you used in the example, were not quotes. They were 'smart quotes', if you look carefully, you will see what I mean. They are slightly slanted.

Answer (score 0):

Let suppose you've your line of text in a file named **sentence.txt**.

`sentence.txt`

```
As a manager, he told FIFA TV he communicates his messages in a measured way. "I'm not one of the lads," Southgate explained.
```

Now, you can try the below code to read the above line and extract the sub string enclosed within `"` (double quotes).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
with open('sentence.txt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    sentence = f.read().strip();

words = sentence.split('\"');

if len(words) == 3:
    string_in_double_quote = words[1];
    print string_in_double_quote # I'm not one of the lads,
else:
    print 'WARNING: String in text file does not have 2 double quotes, make sure to have it'
```

Comment: this is works, but the ouptut is WARNING even though i copy-paste the text and the code

Comment: Paste me your string, I will check and update it. Let me check what is the issue.

Comment: This is what in my Windows CMD, `e:\Users\Rishikesh\Python3\Practice\DoubleQuoteStringSeparation>python main.py
I'm not one of the lads,`.

Comment: dude, i just paste the text above. im using py 2.7

Comment: Actually you copied the old code (where I'd forgotten to  remove `[1]`). Now you please try the current code.