# How to extract quoted statements in a text file -- Python

Tags: python, text, while-loop, quotes

i want to find all quoted statements in a text file. i wrote a code and it worked at finding the first quoted statement. however when i used **while loop** so it can go all over the text and find them all it didn't work.
here is the code:

```
        quoteStart = fullText.index("\"")
        quoteEnd = fullText.index("\"", quoteStart + 1)
        quotedText = fullText[quoteStart:quoteEnd+1]
        print ("{}:{}".format(quoteStart, quoteEnd))
        print (quotedText)
```

output :

```
250:338

"When we talk about the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombing, we never talk about Shinkolobwe,"
```

how can i add the while loop to go all over the text?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that
 `quoteStart = fullText.index("\"")` will always start in the front of your text.

try out the following:

```
quoteEnd = -1

while True:
    try:
        quoteStart = fullText.index("\"", quoteEnd+1)
        quoteEnd = fullText.index("\"", quoteStart + 1)
    except ValueError:
        break
        
    quotedText = fullText[quoteStart:quoteEnd+1]
    print ("{}:{}".format(quoteStart, quoteEnd))
    print (quotedText)
```

Comment: can you explain why you used  ( quoteEnd = -1 ) though ? i don't really get it :\

Comment: As I always start the loop by looking for the next quote after the position `quoteEnd+1` and I want the first time to start at position `0`, i have to set the initial `quoteEnd=-1`.

Answer (score 0):

It is always good to provide a minimal working example i.e. it would make it easier to answer this question if you provided sample of what's in `fullText`.

You don't need a `while` loop to do this. A regular expression would be a much simpler solution.

Let's assume,
`fullText = '"When we talk about the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombing, we never talk about Shinkolobwe," was what one said and "I agree." was what another said.'`

You could use a regular expression like below.

```
import re

quotedText = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', fullText)

print(quotedText)
```

Result:

`['When we talk about the Hiroshima and Nagasaki bombing, we never talk about Shinkolobwe,', 'I agree.']`

`r'"([^"]*)"'` is a raw string that represents a regular expression to match any number of occurrences of anything except a double quote between two double quotes.

A good explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes).