# Python regular expression for finding string in between the text file

Tags: python, regex, string, text-files

I'm currently working on python code to extract a specific strings on a text file between `' '`. Here's the code I'm working on:

```
import re
pattern = "(\w+'*',)"
with open('C:\Documents and Settings\Ash\Desktop\strcount.txt', "r") as text:
    for line in text:
        print re.findall(pattern, line)
```

and the list of strings in the text file

```
('FLBC8U', 24)
('cHvQuW', 24)
('7FDm@', 24)
('15ii?', 24)
('H!oDe', 24)
('RB6#U', 24)
('uAmer', 24)
('6NmDJ', 24)
('d-MS1', 24)
('Ejf&B', 24)
```

I only wanted to take the string in the middle of `' '` single quotation mark before the comma `,` so the number and the bracket is ignored

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string) or [Regex for quoted string with escaping quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249791/regex-for-quoted-string-with-escaping-quotes)

Answer (score 2):

```
s = "'FLBC8U', 24"

print re.findall("'([^']*)'", s)[0]
FLBC8U
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it for you:

```
(?<=\(')((?!').)*(?=')
```

Explanation [here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%28%27%29%28%28%3F%21%27%29.%29%2a%28%3F%3D%27%29)

Comment: please add some details on why your proposed solution answer the given question. One-line-like answers are likely to be deleted in the future.

Answer (score 0):

My regex:

```
(?<=\').*(?=\',)
```

You can check the result [here](http://regex101.com/r/hY5eE9).

---

By the way, this [site](http://regex101.com/) is quite helpful for playing with regex in python.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern:

```
   \(\'(.*)\',.+\)
```

example: http://regex101.com/r/aZ6tU6

Answer (score 0):

If the strings are simply in a line, you can just do this:

```
>>> "('FLBC8U', 24)"[1:-1].split(',')[0]
"'FLBC8U'"
```