# Parse log text in Python using Regex

Tags: python, parsing, python-2.7, scripting

I've a format like this:

```
att1="value 1" att2="value 2" att3="value 3"
```

for example

```
level="Information" clientAddr="127.0.0.1" action="GetByName" message="Action completed" url="/customers/foo" method="GET"
```

Can I use regex to parse this? inside the values I won't have any embedded quotes but I'll have spaces

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string)

Comment: This regex `"([^"]*)"` would do the job.

Comment: this seems like an XML node attributes - I'd parse it with XML parser instead of regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xml.dom.minidom

def parsed_dict(attrs):
    return dict(xml.dom.minidom.parseString('<node {}/>'.format(attrs)).firstChild.attributes.items())

print parsed_dict('level="Information" clientAddr="127.0.0.1" action="GetByName" message="Action completed" url="/customers/foo" method="GET"')

{u'clientAddr': u'127.0.0.1', u'level': u'Information', u'url': u'/customers/foo', u'action': u'GetByName', u'message': u'Action completed', u'method': u'GET'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Through findall function , you could get the values inside double quotes.

```
>>> import re
>>> m = 'level="Information" clientAddr="127.0.0.1" action="GetByName" message="Action completed" url="/customers/foo" method="GET"'
>>> s = re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', m)
>>> for i in s:
...     print i
... 
Information
127.0.0.1
GetByName
Action completed
/customers/foo
GET
```