# Extracting string between quotes split across multiple lines in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a file containing multiple entries. Each entry is of the following form:

```
"field1","field2","field3","field4","field5"
```

All of the fields are guaranteed to not contain any quotes, however they can contain `,`. The problem is that `field4` can be split across multiple lines. So an example file can look like:

```
"john","male US","done","Some sample text
across multiple lines. There
can be many lines of this","foo bar baz"
"jane","female UK","done","fields can have , in them","abc xyz"
```

I want to extract the fields using Python. If the field would not have been split across multiple lines this would have been simple: [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations). But I can't seem to find a simple way to do this in presence of multiline fields.

EDIT: There are actually five fields. Sorry about the confusion if any. The question has been edited to reflect this.

Comment: The answer to the linked question should work fine. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes. I used it like `for line in file: regex.findall(...)`. The problem happens because it is line by line.

Comment: replace all `"\n"` with `""` or do you need to preserve them?

Comment: But that will then fuse all the fields together.

Comment: Is the file large? Can you read it all into memory?

Comment: Nope. It is ~ 8GB in size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that the `csv` module can solve this problem. It splits correctly with newlines:

```
import csv 

f = open('infile', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for row in reader:
    for field in row:
        print('-- {}'.format(field))
```

It yields:

```
-- john
-- male US
-- done
-- Some sample text
across multiple lines. There
can be many lines of this
-- foo bar baz
-- jane
-- female UK
-- done
-- fields can have , in them
-- abc xyz
```

Comment: I thought about json, but it do not likes \n in value.

Comment: This solution might be good enough without the `newline` argument to `open` and it would work directly in Python 2. I understand why you used it, just thought it was worth noting.

Answer (score 1):

The answer from the question you linked worked for me:

```
import re
f = open("test.txt")
text = f.read()

string_list = re.findall('"([^"]*"', text)
```

At this point, string_list contains your strings.  Now, these strings can have line breaks in them, but you can use

```
new_string = string_list.replace("\n", " ")
```

to clean that up.

Comment: alecxe:  Sure, and in that case one might need to do something more sophisticated, like reading the file in chunks and parsing them.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
awk '{FS=','} /pattern if needed/{print $0}' fname
```

Comment: Did you mean to use RS instead of OFS? Even then this does not work since a fields itself can have `,`, and the fields are multiline. Awk only reads a file line by line.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the input to this file, you need to sanitize it beforehand by replacing `\n`  with something ([\n]?) before putting the values into a comma-separated list.

Or, instead of saving strings -- save them as r-strings.

Then, use the `csv` module to parse it quickly with predefined separators, encoding and quotechar