# Stripping string in python between quotes

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

I have a string

```
text:u'tsod'
```

The "text:U" is part of the string.

I want to strip only the characters between the single quotes. I know how to strip based on location but i do not know how to strip based on a value in my case the " ' " , I simply want to extract "tsod"

Also , how will python understand which is the starting " ' " and which is the ending " ' " in order to perform the strip since both are same characters.

Comment: `"text:u'tsod'".split("'")[1]`

Comment: @falsetru WHATT ??? Its that simple? OMG python is awesome!!  works like a charm. Thank you can you explain how it works? i mean what is the 1 at the end

Comment: @falsetru Yeah thank you for the  tip , i thought there was some python function to do that but it seems applying common sense is the secret function :-p I am pathetic !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have multiple pairs of quotes, then this solution may help:

```
import re
strng = "text:u'tsod';text2:u'tsod2';text3:u'tsod3'"
qlist = re.findall("\'(.*?)\'",strng)
```

Then `qlist` will have : `['tsod', 'tsod2', 'tsod3']`

Comment: WOAH, this is exactly what i needed .. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. The regular expression module is extremely useful for string manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

You can split on the inverted comma `"'"`:

```
>>> s = "text:u'tsod'".split("'")
>>> s
['text:u', 'tsod', '']
>>> s[1]
'tsod'
```

Comment: Nice , i see so you split the text into three parts and then you select the second section , ROFL i am dumb thank you kind sir!

Comment: @Anarach Anyone could easily overlook these things. Credits to falsetru  who had commented before I posted the answer.

Comment: Thank you guys, I picked up python recently and I am loving it thanks to people like yourself and falsetru

Answer (score -1):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/69891301/1531728

Test with the loop/enumeration approach [Booboo2020], and modified regular expression from [Avinash2021] and [user17405772021] for substrings embedded within single quotes.

Swap the positions of the double quotes and the single quotes for the modification.

References:

- [Booboo2020]
- [Avinash2021]
- [user17405772021]

My solution is:

```
import re
my_substrings = []
test_string = "text:u'tsod'"
for values in re.findall("'(.+?)'", test_string):
    my_substrings.append(values)
print(" my_substrings are:",my_substrings,"=")
```

Solution tested more extensively.

```
import re
my_substrings = []
my_strings = ["SetVariables 'a' 'b' 'c' ", "d2efw   f 'first' +&%#$%'second',vwrfhir, d2e   u'third' dwedew", "'uno'?>P>MNUIHUH~!@#$%^&*()_+=0trewq'due'        'tre'fef    fre f", "       'uno''dos'      'tres'", "'unu''doua''trei'", "      'um'                    'dois'           'tres'                  "]
for current_test_string in my_strings:
    """
        For each test string, extract substrings embedded within
            single quotes.
    """
    for values in re.findall("'(.+?)'", current_test_string):
        # Append found embedded substring into the list of substrings.
        my_substrings.append(values)
    print(" my_substrings are:",my_substrings,"=")
    my_substrings = []
```

Alternate regular expressions to use are:

- re.findall('"(.+?)"', current_test_string) [Avinash2021] [user17405772021]
- re.findall("'(.*?)'", current_test_string) [Shelvington2020]
- re.findall(r"'(.+?)'", current_test_string) [Lundberg2012] [Avinash2021]
- re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", current_test_string) [Lundberg2012] [Avinash2021]
- re.findall(r"'[']", current_test_string) [Muthupandi2019]
- re.findall(r"'([^']*)'", current_test_string) [Pieters2014]
- re.findall(r"'(?:(?:(?!(?<!\)').)*)'", current_test_string) # Causes double quotes to remain in the strings, but can be removed via other means. [Booboo2020]
- re.findall(r"'(.*?)(?<!\)'", current_test_string) [Hassan2014]
- re.findall("'[^']*'", current_test_string) # Causes double quotes to remain in the strings, but can be removed via other means. [Martelli2013]
- re.findall("'([^']*)'", current_test_string) [jspcal2014]
- re.findall("'(.*?)'", current_test_string) [akhilmd2016]

The `current_test_string.split("\"")` approach works if the strings have patterns in which substrings are embedded within quotation marks. *This is because it uses the double quotation mark in this example as a delimiter to tokenize the string, and accepts substrings that are not embedded within double quotation marks as valid substring extractions from the string.*

References:

- [Avinash2021] Arvind Kumar Avinash, Answer to ``Extract text between quotation using regex python'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, October 12, 2021. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543129/1531728 and [Extract text between quotation using regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542978/extract-text-between-quotation-using-regex-python/69543129#69543129;) November 8, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [user17405772021] user1740577, Answer to ``Extract text between quotation using regex python'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, October 12, 2021. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543030/1531728 and [Extract text between quotation using regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542978/extract-text-between-quotation-using-regex-python/69543030#69543030;) November 8, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Shelvington2020] Iain Shelvington, Answer to ``Extracting only words out of a mixed string in Python [duplicate]'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, January 5, 2020. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59598630/1531728 and [Extracting only words out of a mixed string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598565/extracting-only-words-out-of-a-mixed-string-in-python/59598630#59598630;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Lundberg2012] Johan Lundberg, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 1, 2012. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519934/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/9519934#9519934;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Muthupandi2019] Daniel Muthupandi and trotta, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, August 3, 2019. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337020/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/63707053#63707053;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Booboo2020] Booboo, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63707053/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/63707053#63707053;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Pieters2014] Martijn Pieters, Answer to ``Extract a string between double quotes'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735466/1531728 and [Extract a string between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes/22735466#22735466;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Hassan2014] Sabuj Hassan, Answer to ``Extract a string between double quotes'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735480/1531728 and [Extract a string between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes/22735480#22735480;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Martelli2013] Alex Martelli and Sumit Singh, Answer to "Extract string from between quotations", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, March 14, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076357/1531728 and [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations/2076357#2076357;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [jspcal2014] jspcal, Answer to "Extract string from between quotations", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, March 14, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076356/1531728 and [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations/2076356#2076356;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [akhilmd2016] akhilmd, Answer to "Stripping string in python between quotes", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, July 2, 2016. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38161072/1531728 and ; November 5, 2021 was the last accessed date.