# Extracting only words out of a mixed string in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am working on a topic modelling task and have the unknown topics in the following form

```
 topic = 0.2*"firstword" + 0.2*"secondword" + 0.2*"thirdword" + 0.2*"fourthword" + 0.2*"fifthword"
```

I want a regex.findall() function to return a list containing only the words e.g :

```
['firstword', 'secondword', 'thirdword', 'fourthword', 'fifthword']
```

I have tried using the regex functions :

```
regex.findall(r'\w+', topic)  and 
regex.findall(r'\D\w+', topic)
```

but none of them can eliminate the numbers properly.
Can someone help me find out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is `topic`? `str`?

Comment: Yes topic is of 'str' type

Comment: @SoumyaChakraborty can you share the actual value of the `topic` string? is it `'0.2*"firstword" + 0.2*"secondword" + 0.2*"thirdword" + 0.2*"fourthword" + 0.2*"fifthword"'`?

Comment: If I type print(topic) it displays  :   0.2*"firstword" + 0.2*"secondword" + 0.2*"thirdword" + 0.2*"fourthword" + 0.2*"fifthword"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `topic` is the string

```
topic = '0.2*"firstword" + 0.2*"secondword" + 0.2*"thirdword" + 0.2*"fourthword" + 0.2*"fifthword"'
```

Then the following regex will return what you need

```
re.findall('"(.*?)"', topic)
```

It finds all strings that are contained within double-quotes (")

Answer (score 1):

You can try in two ways:

The first, and simpler, you iterate over the string and keep only the letters like this:

```
''.join(letter for letter in topic if letter.isalpha())
```

Otherwise you can use regular expressions like this:

```
re.sub('[^a-zA-Z]+', '', topic)
```

This expression keeps only letters il lower and upper case.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this exact problem myself. My solution was:

```
    import re

    def extract_tokens_from_topic(self, raw_topic):            
        raw_topic_string = raw_topic.__str__() # convert list to string
        return re.findall(r"'(.*?)'", raw_topic_string)
```

where `raw_topic` came from `raw_topic = lda_model.show_topic(topic_no)`

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way to do:

```
>>> import re

>>> topic = "0.2*firstword" + "0.2*secondword" + "0.2*thirdword" + "0.2*fourthword" + "0.2*fifthword"

>>> re.sub(r'[ˆ\d]\W',' ', topic).strip().split()
>>> ['firstword', 'secondword', 'thirdword', 'fourthword', 'fifthword']
```

Comment: The probabilities are not inside the double quotes, just the consisting words are, but anyways I got your point. Thanks