# Extract text between quotation using regex python

Tags: python, regex

I have tried extracting text inside quotations ""

```
file content:
"abc"
"ABC. XYZ"
"1 - 2 - 3"
```

code i've tried using regex

```
title = re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', filecontent)
print(title)
```

Output:

```
['abc']
[] # Some lines comes out like this empty
['1 - 2 - 3']
```

Some of the lines comes empty not sure why. is there an alternative better way to do this?

Comment: ok, but why tho?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to extract some substring out of a string, you can go for [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

**Demo:**

```
import re

str_list = ['"abc"', '"ABC. XYZ"', '"1 - 2 - 3"']

for str in str_list:
    search_str = re.search('"(.+?)"', str)
    if search_str:
        print(search_str.group(1))
```

**Output:**

```
abc
ABC. XYZ
1 - 2 - 3
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, Do you try this?

```
filecontent = '''
"abc"
"ABC. XYZ"
"1 - 2 - 3"
'''

re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', filecontent)
```

Output:

```
['abc', 'ABC. XYZ', '1 - 2 - 3']
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is:

```
import re
my_strings = ['SetVariables "a" "b" "c" ', 'd2efw   f "first" +&%#$%"second",vwrfhir, d2e   u"third" dwedew', '"uno"?>P>MNUIHUH~!@#$%^&*()_+=0trewq"due"        "tre"fef    fre f', '       "uno""dos"      "tres"', '"unu""doua""trei"', '      "um"                    "dois"           "tres"                  ']
my_substrings = []
for current_test_string in my_strings:
    for values in re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', current_test_string):
        my_substrings.append(values)
        #print("values are:",values,"=")
    print(" my_substrings are:",my_substrings,"=")
    my_substrings = []
```

Alternate regular expressions to use are:

- re.findall('"(.+?)"', current_test_string) [Avinash2021] [user17405772021]
- re.findall('"(.*?)"', current_test_string) [Shelvington2020]
- re.findall(r'"(.*?)"', current_test_string) [Lundberg2012] [Avinash2021]
- re.findall(r'"(.+?)"', current_test_string) [Lundberg2012] [Avinash2021]
- re.findall(r'"["]', current_test_string) [Muthupandi2019]
- re.findall(r'"([^"]*)"', current_test_string) [Pieters2014]
- re.findall(r'"(?:(?:(?!(?<!\)").)*)"', current_test_string) # Causes double quotes to remain in the strings, but can be removed via other means. [Booboo2020]
- re.findall(r'"(.*?)(?<!\)"', current_test_string) [Hassan2014]
- re.findall('"[^"]*"', current_test_string) # Causes double quotes to remain in the strings, but can be removed via other means. [Martelli2013]
- re.findall('"([^"]*)"', current_test_string) [jspcal2014]
- re.findall("'(.*?)'", current_test_string) [akhilmd2016]

The `current_test_string.split("\"")` approach works if the strings have patterns in which substrings are embedded within quotation marks. *This is because it uses the double quotation mark in this example as a delimiter to tokenize the string, and accepts substrings that are not embedded within double quotation marks as valid substring extractions from the string.*

References:

- [Avinash2021] Arvind Kumar Avinash, Answer to ``Extract text between quotation using regex python'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, October 12, 2021. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543129/1531728 and [Extract text between quotation using regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542978/extract-text-between-quotation-using-regex-python/69543129#69543129;) November 8, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [user17405772021] user1740577, Answer to ``Extract text between quotation using regex python'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, October 12, 2021. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69543030/1531728 and [Extract text between quotation using regex python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69542978/extract-text-between-quotation-using-regex-python/69543030#69543030;) November 8, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Shelvington2020] Iain Shelvington, Answer to ``Extracting only words out of a mixed string in Python [duplicate]'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, January 5, 2020. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59598630/1531728 and [Extracting only words out of a mixed string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59598565/extracting-only-words-out-of-a-mixed-string-in-python/59598630#59598630;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Lundberg2012] Johan Lundberg, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 1, 2012. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519934/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/9519934#9519934;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Muthupandi2019] Daniel Muthupandi and trotta, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, August 3, 2019. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57337020/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/63707053#63707053;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Booboo2020] Booboo, Answer to ``Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63707053/1531728 and [Python Regex to find a string in double quotes within a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519734/python-regex-to-find-a-string-in-double-quotes-within-a-string/63707053#63707053;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Pieters2014] Martijn Pieters, Answer to ``Extract a string between double quotes'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735466/1531728 and [Extract a string between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes/22735466#22735466;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Hassan2014] Sabuj Hassan, Answer to ``Extract a string between double quotes'', Stack Exchange, Inc., New York, NY, March 29, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22735480/1531728 and [Extract a string between double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22735440/extract-a-string-between-double-quotes/22735480#22735480;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [Martelli2013] Alex Martelli and Sumit Singh, Answer to "Extract string from between quotations", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, March 14, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076357/1531728 and [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations/2076357#2076357;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [jspcal2014] jspcal, Answer to "Extract string from between quotations", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, March 14, 2014. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076356/1531728 and [Extract string from between quotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076343/extract-string-from-between-quotations/2076356#2076356;) November 6, 2021 was the last accessed date.
- [akhilmd2016] akhilmd, Answer to "Stripping string in python between quotes", Stack Exchange Inc., New York, NY, July 2, 2016. Available online from Stack Exchange Inc.: Stack Overflow: Questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38161072/1531728 and ; November 5, 2021 was the last accessed date.